# Timeout command - echo output from shell script

Tags: linux, bash, sh, gnu

I wanted to put a timeout on my import script.

When using `timeout` the import script does not output via the `loadImport.sh`. This is troublesome since `loadImport.sh` is the script loaded by a php file and thus no output is seen.

The first script `loadImport.sh` loads the import script `doImport.sh` with a timeout.

`loadImport.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

IMPORTLOG='/usr/local/bin/import.log'
DBNAME=$1

timeout --kill-after=90s 60s sudo ./doImport.sh $DBNAME
if (($? == 124)); then
  echo "Import timed out" | tee -a $IMPORTLOG
  exit 124
fi
```

How do I get the output from `doImport.sh` with the line `timeout --kill-after=90s 60s sudo ./doImport.sh $DBNAME`?

Comment: What do you mean "get the output?"  Do you want it in a file or in a variable?

Comment: There's no need for `tee` here; `echo "Import timed out" >> "$IMPORTLOG"`.

Comment: What version of `timeout` are you using that has a `--kill-after` option?

Comment: I think you just want to drop the `echo` in `sudo echo ./doImport.sh "$DBNAME"`. Right now, you aren't running `./doImport.sh` at all.

Comment: @EricRenouf I want it to echo when running `timeout --kill-after=90s 60s sudo echo ./doImport.sh $DBNAME` but with the output of `doImport.sh`  @chepner true and timeout version is 8.21. Forgot to remove the echo from that codeline.

Comment: Did removing the `echo` solve the problem then?

Comment: @EricRenouf No, removing `echo` did only correct my question, the problem was solved by using `source`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`source` solved my problem.

I was using it wrong first since in combination with `sudo` it has to be used like this `sudo -s`

Changing my script like this:
`timeout --kill-after=90s 60s sudo -s ./doImport.sh $DBNAME` 
was the answer